# breadcrumbs with gretel gem working on dev environment but not working on production environment on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

i am working in a website hosted on Heroku, i used gretel gem for making breadcrumbs.

the breadcrumbs is working fine on dev environment but in Heroku this does not work.

On Heroku the breadcrumbs look like this:

[image]

I not have idea why this not working on Heroku. if this working very fine on dev environment

any idea?

Breadcrumbs code:

```
crumb :root do
  link "Galeria", root_path
end

crumb :category do |category|
  link "Categoria: #{category.name.titleize}", category
  parent :root
end

crumb :picture do |picture, category|
  link "Viendo la imagen: #{picture.title.titleize}"
  parent :category, category
end
```

Layout with breadcrumb:

```
.container
  = breadcrumbs pretext: "Estas en: ", display_single_fragment: true, style: :bootstrap
```

Sorry my bad english...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well. i answer myself.

reading the  slim documentation.
i found that I must use == symbol instead = to avoid escaped html code.